# Collinearity of 3 vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

a,b,c are three non-coplanar vectors. The points P,Q,R with position vectors:

$$\mathrm P: a-2b+3c; \\
\mathrm Q: 2a+\mathrm Xb-4c \\
\mathrm R: -7b+10c$$

will be collinear if the value of "X" is?

Comment: Your own effort first please.

Comment: homework question? If so, use the homework tag.

Comment: @Paul I know that three points with position vectors a, b, c are collinear if there exist a scalar x, y, z, not all zero simultaneously such that xa+yb+zc=0 also given x+y+z=0.

I tried to use this but couldn't figure out how to.

Comment: @FundThmCalculus The homework tag doesn't exist anymore.  It was [deprecated](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what).

Comment: That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three vectors are coplanar iff they are linearly dependent, and this means that:
$$
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&3\\
2&X&-4\\
0&-7&10
\end{bmatrix}
= 0
$$

Comment: Unfortunately, the corresponding value of X (=-11) from this determinant does not satisfy the answer to this question.

Comment: I found$10X-30=0$, so: $X=3$.

Comment: Just realised the fallacy. Solved.

Comment: wait! You got correct answer, but your reasoning was wrong. You found the condition for 3 vectors $0P$, $0Q$ and $0R$ to be in the same plane. But in general this does not mean the points $P, Q$ and $R$ will be on the same line!

Comment: @lesnik: the OP asks for **coplanar** vectors, not on the same line.

Comment: No, Bloopy asks what are the conditions for these 3 points to be collinear!

Answer (score 0):

Three points $P, Q, R$ are collinear if vectors $PQ$ and $PR$ "point to the same direction". That means $PQ = x * PR$. I suggest to calculate $PQ$ and $PR$ in terms of $a, b, c$ and check if they can "point to the same direction" for some $X$.